# How to create one XML file for each record from a XML file export from MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Good day to everyone. I was exported the a set of data in xml from MYSQL database. But, I want to separate the existing xml file into 1 ROW in 1 XML file. The example is as below:

Exported XML result from database:

Filename: **result01.xml**

Script in file:

```
<ROWDATA>
<ROW>
    <DOCKEY>57911</DOCKEY>
    <DOCNO>MY1113</DOCNO>
    <DOCDATE>20141201</DOCDATE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DOCKEY>57913</DOCKEY>
    <DOCNO>MY1114</DOCNO>
    <DOCDATE>20141201</DOCDATE>

</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DOCKEY>57915</DOCKEY>
    <DOCNO>MY1115</DOCNO>
    <DOCDATE>20141201</DOCDATE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DOCKEY>57915</DOCKEY>
    <DOCNO>MY1115</DOCNO>
    <DOCDATE>20141201</DOCDATE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
    <DOCKEY>57957</DOCKEY>
    <DOCNO>MY1160</DOCNO>
    <DOCDATE>20141201</DOCDATE>
</ROW>
</ROWDATA>
```

But what I need is to create one file per row:

Filename: **57911.MY1113.xml**
XML in file:

```
<ROWDATA>
    <ROW DOCKEY="57911" DOCNO="MY1113" DOCDATE="20141201">
</ROW></ROWDATA>
```

Filename: **57913.MY1114.xml**
XML in file:

```
<ROWDATA>
      <ROW DOCKEY="57913" DOCNO="MY1114" DOCDATE="20141201">
</ROW></ROWDATA>
```

Does anyone know if there's a simple way of creating multiple XML files

as I mentioned. Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use xslt or just write a script In your preferred language to do this... Is probably use PHP myself but anything with an xml lib would work.

Comment: Hi, thanks on your comment. But, I would like to have something like examples and more technically reply on this case like suggestion on using PHP to write as above scenario with example. Thanks.

Comment: why you want to do this?

Comment: I need to import my existing data to other third party software.

Answer (score 1):

So with PHP it would look something like this:

```
$outDir = 'path/to/output/dir';
$src = 'result01.xml';

// create the document and load our source xml file
$srcDom = new DOMDocument();
$srcDom->load($src);

// pull all the ROW elements with xpath
$rowFinder = new DOMXpath($srcDom);
$rows = $rowFinder->query('//ROW');

// loop over the ROWs
foreach($rows as $row) {

   // create a new document for our export.
   $outDoc = new DOMDocument();
   // create a ROWDATA element for our root node
   $outRoot = $outDoc->createElement('ROWDATA');

   // import the ROW node (and all its descendents into the new document
   $outRow = $outDoc->importNode($row, true);

   $filename = array(
      'DOCKEY' => '',
      'DOCNO' => ''
   );
   foreach ($outRow->childNodes as $datum) {
      // add the values for segements of the filename
      if (array_key_exists($datum->nodeName, $filename)) {
         $filename[$datum->nodeName] = $datum->nodeValue;
      }
   }

   // append the ROW to ROWDATA
   $outRoot->appendChild($outRow);

   // append the ROWDATA to our document
   $outDoc->appendChild($outRoot);

   // save the xml to file using strtr to create the file name from
   // our array of filename segments
   $outDoc->save(strtr($outDir . '/DOCKEY.DOCNO.xml', $filename));
}
```

Comment: Gorgeous!!!! Fantastic!!!! Very nice output!!!! Thank you! Thank you, Mr. Prodigitalson.....